# Resetting the row number for when a value changes

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new to using ROW_NUMBER() in SQL and I'm in the situation where I want the row number to start from 1 whenever the margin gets changed.

The situation is slightly convoluted since I want the row number to reset irrespective if the margin was the same value before. Below is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Any help on the above would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your version of SQL, and what is the type of the `MARGIN` column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using bigquery and the type is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, and one approach uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAMPAIGN_NAME ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAMPAIGN_NAME, MARGIN ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT CAMPAIGN_NAME, DATE, MARGIN, REVENUE,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAMPAIGN_NAME, MARGIN, r1 - r2
                          ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS RN
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    CAMPAIGN_NAME,
    DATE DESC;
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thank you!